# Trying to find a fair equation

Tags: probability

First of, I am no mathematician. I do know how to code (a little), let me introduce you to my problem below, and see what I've tried sofar. Some assistance/directions would be awesome, thanks.

As a hobby I am creating a game with **5** turns for each of **2** players, this could either be a fighting game or soccer game and so on

In my example the possible move choices are:

```
[HK, MK, LK, HP, MP, LP, HB, MB, LB]
```

So there are **81** permutations of an outcome, which I have assigned to an outcome mapping [either (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1) or (1, 1)]:

```
matrix = {
    ('HB', 'HB'): (0, 0),
    ('HB', 'HK'): (1, 0),
    ('HB', 'HP'): (1, 0),
    ('HB', 'LB'): (0, 0),
    ('HB', 'LK'): (0, 1),
    ('HB', 'LP'): (0, 1),
    ('HB', 'MB'): (0, 0),
    ('HB', 'MK'): (0, 1),
    ('HB', 'MP'): (0, 1),
    ('HK', 'HB'): (0, 1),
    ('HK', 'HK'): (1, 1),
    ('HK', 'HP'): (1, 1),
    ('HK', 'LB'): (0, 0),
    ('HK', 'LK'): (0, 1),
    ('HK', 'LP'): (0, 1),
    ('HK', 'MB'): (1, 0),
    ('HK', 'MK'): (1, 1),
    ('HK', 'MP'): (1, 1),
    ('HP', 'HB'): (0, 1),
    ('HP', 'HK'): (1, 1),
    ('HP', 'HP'): (1, 1),
    ('HP', 'LB'): (0, 0),
    ('HP', 'LK'): (0, 1),
    ('HP', 'LP'): (0, 1),
    ('HP', 'MB'): (1, 0),
    ('HP', 'MK'): (1, 1),
    ('HP', 'MP'): (1, 1),
    ('LB', 'HB'): (0, 0),
    ('LB', 'HK'): (0, 0),
    ('LB', 'HP'): (0, 0),
    ('LB', 'LB'): (0, 0),
    ('LB', 'LK'): (1, 0),
    ('LB', 'LP'): (1, 0),
    ('LB', 'MB'): (0, 0),
    ('LB', 'MK'): (0, 1),
    ('LB', 'MP'): (0, 1),
    ('LK', 'HB'): (1, 0),
    ('LK', 'HK'): (1, 0),
    ('LK', 'HP'): (1, 0),
    ('LK', 'LB'): (0, 1),
    ('LK', 'LK'): (1, 1),
    ('LK', 'LP'): (1, 1),
    ('LK', 'MB'): (1, 0),
    ('LK', 'MK'): (1, 1),
    ('LK', 'MP'): (1, 1),
    ('LP', 'HB'): (1, 0),
    ('LP', 'HK'): (1, 0),
    ('LP', 'HP'): (1, 0),
    ('LP', 'LB'): (0, 1),
    ('LP', 'LK'): (1, 1),
    ('LP', 'LP'): (1, 1),
    ('LP', 'MB'): (1, 0),
    ('LP', 'MK'): (1, 1),
    ('LP', 'MP'): (1, 1),
    ('MB', 'HB'): (0, 0),
    ('MB', 'HK'): (0, 1),
    ('MB', 'HP'): (0, 1),
    ('MB', 'LB'): (0, 0),
    ('MB', 'LK'): (0, 1),
    ('MB', 'LP'): (0, 1),
    ('MB', 'MB'): (0, 0),
    ('MB', 'MK'): (1, 0),
    ('MB', 'MP'): (1, 0),
    ('MK', 'HB'): (1, 0),
    ('MK', 'HK'): (1, 1),
    ('MK', 'HP'): (1, 1),
    ('MK', 'LB'): (1, 0),
    ('MK', 'LK'): (1, 1),
    ('MK', 'LP'): (1, 1),
    ('MK', 'MB'): (0, 1),
    ('MK', 'MK'): (1, 1),
    ('MK', 'MP'): (1, 1),
    ('MP', 'HB'): (1, 0),
    ('MP', 'HK'): (1, 1),
    ('MP', 'HP'): (1, 1),
    ('MP', 'LB'): (1, 0),
    ('MP', 'LK'): (1, 1),
    ('MP', 'LP'): (1, 1),
    ('MP', 'MB'): (0, 1),
    ('MP', 'MK'): (1, 1),
    ('MP', 'MP'): (1, 1)
}
```

The mapping is a way to see which move wins over the other, but I would also like it to be the base of a score engine.

**Problem**
In my ideal scenario each permutation of 5 turns has a near even chance of player 1 or player 2 winning or they draw.

Of course this works if both players choose each turn completely random, I have ran a few million iterations of 5 turns and these are the results:

```
player1 wins ~37.59 %
player2 wins ~37.59 %
p1 and p2 draw ~24.82 %
```

Pretty cool, except when a player does not choose turns randomly, e.g.

```
player1 only picks "LK"
player2 picks random still

p1 wins ~78.64666667 %
p2 wins ~7.56666667 %
p1 and p2 draw ~13.78666667 %
```

I only deterministic know how to solve this, I have changed every 1 score to 100 and then started adjusting values to (75, 0) if they seemed too strong and so on. This led me to a matrix where 5 successive LK's only had a 49.63% chance of winning. However the matrix is still very unbalanced and seems very arbitraire.

How can I "solve" this puzzle with an equation?

Here's a simplified matrix I came up with:

```
MOVE    WIN / DRAW / LOSS / MISS
HK        1 / 4 / 3 / 1 (win) MB (draw) HP, HK, MK, MP (lose) HB, LP, LK (miss) LB
MK        2 / 6 / 1 / 0 (win) HB, LB (draw) HK, MK, LK, LP, HP, MP (lose) MB (miss)
LK        4 / 4 / 1 / 0 (win) HK, HP, HB, MB (draw) MK, MP, LK, LP (lose) LB (miss)

HP        1 / 4 / 3 / 1 (win) MB (draw) HP, HK, MK, MP (lose) HB, LP, LK, (miss) LB
MP        2 / 6 / 1 / 0 (win) HB, LB (draw) HK, MK, LK, LP, HP, MP (lose) MB (miss)
LP        4 / 4 / 1 / 0 (win) HK, HP, HB, MB (draw) MK, MP, LK, LP (lose) LB (miss)

HB        2 / 0 / 4 / 3 (win) HK, HP (draw) (lose) MK, MP, LK, LP (miss) HB, MB, LB
MB        2 / 0 / 4 / 3 (win) MK, MP (draw) (lose) HK, HP, LK, LP (miss) HB, MB, LB
LB        2 / 0 / 4 / 3 (win) LK, LP (draw) (lose) MK, MP, HK, HP (miss) HB, MB, LB
```

**UPDATE**

After using Travis's idea (see comments) I found after little attempts something like this has positive effects:

```
HK = 3
MK = 2
LK = 1
HP = 3
MP = 2
LP = 1
HB = 3
MB = 4
LB = 2
```

Where points are only awarded when a certain player hits, e.g.

```
(HK, HK) => both players HIT, so they receive their reward (3, 3) et cetera, this let me to the following results (I think everything under 50% is a pretty cool start)
```

Results (not too many iterations and python random, isn't very good at being random)

```
TEST random
p1 won 45.01333333 %
p2 won 43.58666667 %
p1 and p2 draw 11.4 %


TEST 5x LK
p1 won 43.71333333 %
p2 won 40.26666667 %
p1 and p2 draw 16.02 %


TEST 5x MK
p1 won 48.88666667 %
p2 won 41.57333333 %
p1 and p2 draw 9.54 %


TEST 5x HK
p1 won 43.72 %
p2 won 44.54 %
p1 and p2 draw 11.74 %


TEST 5x LB
p1 won 36.19333333 %
p2 won 37.40666667 %
p1 and p2 draw 26.4 %


TEST 5x MB
p1 won 44.08 %
p2 won 47.96666667 %
p1 and p2 draw 7.95333333 %


TEST 5x HB
p1 won 42.62 %
p2 won 47.72 %
p1 and p2 draw 9.66 %
```

Comment: To be clear, do both $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$ represent a draw? (This is consistent with a few checks across the two tables.) It's not clear to me how the number 5 of turns is relevant here, but it seems to me one option is to assign the nine outcomes the numbers $0, \ldots, 8$ and declare that a pair $(x, y)$ results in a win for player 1 if $x - y \equiv 1, 2, 3, 4 \pmod 9$, a win for player 2 if $x - y \equiv -1, -2, -3, -4 \pmod 9$, and a tie if $x = y$. This setup has the maybe-desirable property that the outcome does not depend on the labeling on the two players as players $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @Travis Yes correct, a draw or miss actually (1, 1 indicates hits while 0, 0 does not) see the simplified table. I can understand now that the amount of turns is irrelevant as 1 should have the same outcome. Thanks for the comment, I will try to embed the equation! I should probably mention that it should ideally be just as appealing to pick "LB" as "MK" without forcing picks.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you're looking for---is it essentially a variant of rock-paper-scissors with 9 elements, and possibly allowing ties even when the two players pick different objects?